# Generate n appointments in the next m months

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I work with an API where I need to write code to generate n appointment dates in the coming m months (from today). For the purpose, I write a Random date generator class provided. One condition is I need to use the `java.sql.Date` for the class.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomDate {


    private final Random random;

    private final Date currentDate;
    private final int months;

    public RandomDate(Random random, Date currentDate, int months) {

        this.random = random;
        this.currentDate = currentDate;
        this.months = months;
    }

    public Date getRangeEndDate() {

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(this.currentDate.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, this.months * 30);

    return new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}

public Date generateRandomDate(Date endDate) {

    int start = (int) this.currentDate.toLocalDate().toEpochDay();
    int end = (int) endDate.toLocalDate().toEpochDay();

    long randomDay = start + random.nextInt(end - start);
    return Date.valueOf(LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay));
}

}
```

I have an issue that within the code I use the time classes from 3 different packages (java.sql, java.time, and java.util). How can I write it more elegantly?

Comment: Why would three different packages be a problem? Especially when one of them is `java.util`?

Comment: I updated the code with only using the `java.time.LocalDate`

Comment: Why do you need to use `java.sql.Date`? This requirement may be 20 years old. Current code uses `java.time.LocalDate` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential part of your code is:

```
static LocalDate random(LocalDate start, int months, Random rnd) {
    LocalDate end = start.plusMonths(months);
    int days = (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
    return start.plusDays(rnd.nextInt(days + 1));
}
```

I have no idea why you need more code than this to express the idea.

I don't see any practical reason to use either the old and ugly `java.util.Date` or the even uglier `java.util.Calendar` or the inappropriate `java.sql.Date` (since this code has nothing to do with databases, let alone SQL). All you need are the classes from `java.time`, and `java.time.temporal`.

Answer (score -1):

I updated the code with only using the `java.time.LocalDate`

```
public class RandomDate {

    private final LocalDate today;

    private final Random random;
    private final int months;


    public RandomDate(Random random, int months) {

        this.today = LocalDate.now();

        this.random = random;
        this.months = months;
    }


    public LocalDate getRangeEndDate() {

        LocalDate rangeEndDay = this.today.plusDays(this.months * 30);
        return rangeEndDay;
    }

    public LocalDate generateRandomDate(LocalDate endDate) {

        int start = (int) this.today.toEpochDay();
        int end = (int) endDate.toEpochDay();

        long randomDay = start + random.nextInt(end - start);
        return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(randomDay);
    }


    public LocalDate getToday() {
        return today;
    }

    public Random getRandom() {
        return random;
    }

    public int getMonths() {
        return months;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof RandomDate)) return false;
        RandomDate that = (RandomDate) o;
        return getMonths() == that.getMonths() &&
                Objects.equals(getToday(), that.getToday()) &&
                Objects.equals(getRandom(), that.getRandom());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(getToday(), getRandom(), getMonths());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RandomDate{" +
                "today=" + today +
                ", random=" + random +
                ", months=" + months +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is overly long and hard-codes a month to be exactly 30 days, which is wrong. It also creates a class `RandomDate` for no apparent reason when a utility function would serve the same purpose.